# Disabling JS/CSS bundling if debug=true in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-optimization, bundletransformer

I am using [BundleTransformer](https://github.com/Taritsyn/BundleTransformer) to bundle and minify JS/CSS in a legacy ASP.NET WebForms app. However, I'd like to **disable** bundling if `<compilation debug="true">` in Web.config.

- Current Behavior: If `debug=true`, resources are still bundled together, but nothing is minified.
- Desired Behavior: Bundling and minification only occur if `debug=false`. **Otherwise**, references to the individual scripts and stylesheets are rendered in the HTML.

Is this possible?

Below is an example of how I currently create one of the bundles:

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
var jsMinifier = new BundleTransformer.JsMin.Minifiers.CrockfordJsMinifier();
var customJsTransformer = new BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.ScriptTransformer(jsMinifier);
var CustomJsBundle = new BundleTransformer.Core.Bundles.CustomScriptBundle("~/bundles/CustomJsBundle");

foreach (var item in jsFiles)
{
    CustomJsBundle.Include(item);
}

CustomJsBundle.Transforms.Clear();
CustomJsBundle.Transforms.Add(customJsTransformer);
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(CustomJsBundle);
```

**Navigation.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" CodeFile="Navigation.master.cs" Inherits="Main_Nav" %>
<%@ Import Namespace= "System.Web.Optimization" %>
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <%= Scripts.Render("~/bundles/CustomJsBundle") %> 
        <!-- if debug=true, I'd like the server to just render references to the individual script files
        instead of the bundle -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- other markup -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The `Scripts.Render` call in `Navigation.master` always displays a bundle, even if debug is true. I'd like it to render the bundle only if debug is false. Otherwise, I'd like script tags to each individual script file rendered instead for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this for now by using the [`RenderFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj659006(v=vs.110)) method when in DEBUG mode. Otherwise, I use the usual `Render` method.

For example, in my **Navigation.master**:

```
<% #if DEBUG %>
<%= Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}'/></script>", "~/bundles/CustomJsBundle") %>
<% #else %>
<%= Scripts.Render("~/bundles/CustomJsBundle") %>
<% #endif %>
```

This has the desired effect of:

- In DEBUG mode, render script tags with the individual files.
- Otherwise, a single script tag with the bundle is rendered.

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this, but if so, please comment or submit an answer. I tried other potential solutions, such as setting `EnableOptimizations` to `false`, and clearing the BundleTable, but this is the only solution that has worked.